# Copying and Inserting Row (with Formulas) Everywhere Column A has a *

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

**TL;DR** - copy row 2 and insert everywhere (one row above) that Column A contains a "*" character.

Hi All. I'm trying to use Google Apps Script to build out an automated feature that will copy a row (with formulas) and insert this copied row everywhere that a defined criteria is met (column A has a *). I have been able to write (1) a script that will insert a blank row everywhere there is a * and (2) a script that will copy formulas and insert to the last row - but I haven't been able to merge the two successfully.

I so far have the following, which feels close - but have not been able to tweak further to obtain the desired results:

```
function insertRecord() {

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sh = ss.getActiveSheet();                     
  var lRow = sh.getLastRow();                       
  var lCol = sh.getLastColumn();                    

  var range = sh.getRange(2,1,1,lCol);              
  var formulas = range.getFormulas();               

  var values = sh.getRange('A:A').getValues();

  for ( var i = values.length-1 ; i >= 0 ; i-- )    
    if (values[i][0] == "*")      
      sh.insertRowBefore(i+1)                             
      var newRange = sh.getRange(lRow, 1, 1, lCol)   
      range.copyTo(newRange);                       
}
```

Please review my [Google Sheets template](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1nJeYkSbhqdTzrgcmE8rocKgueDWwHP895S-HJRdZxMY/edit?usp=sharing) here. Let me know if you have any questions! And thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this?

```
function insertRecord() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sh = ss.getActiveSheet();
  var lRow = sh.getLastRow();
  var lCol = sh.getLastColumn();

  var range = sh.getRange(2,1,1,lCol);
  var values = sh.getRange('A:A').getValues();

  for ( var i = values.length-1 ; i >= 0 ; i-- ) {
    if (values[i][0] == "*") {
      sh.insertRowBefore(i+1)
      var newRange = sh.getRange(i+1, 1, 1, lCol)
      range.copyTo(newRange);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: That looks exactly right. Gosh, I was so close. Appreciate your help!